# appearance: button causes element to shift in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a div I'm adding `appearance: button` style to it. This works but it causes a shift in Firefox, I suspect it is because of the border but using `box-sizing:border-box` doesn't stop it. I also tried adding width and height but it still shifts.

http://jsfiddle.net/2CEuu/2/

```
<div id="add-new-complaint">
    <div class="plus 3"></div>
    Add new Complaint
</div>
```

```css
[id|=add-new]{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
[id|=add-new]:hover{
    -webkit-appearance:button;
    -moz-appearance:button;
    appearance:button;
}
div.plus{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.plus::before{
    width:100%;
    height:33.333%;
    top:33.333%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background-color:#789dc3;
}
div.plus::after{
    width:33.333%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:33.333%;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background-color:#789dc3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can target only Firefox to fix the problem:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    [id|=add-new]:hover{
        padding: 1px;
    }
}
```

Would it work for you?

Comment: Never even seen that that before, I wonder how future proof it is?

Comment: This is based on Mozilla specific CSS extension, I guess it might change in the future. You can check this page:
[Mozilla Extensions @document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions)

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it there are 2 solutions,
Either add/reduce padding/margin accordingly on hover to fake the shift back to its position,
like so:

```
a { margin: 10px 5px; padding: 10px; }
a:hover { padding: 9px 10px 10px 9px; }
```

Or, **better**, add a default transparent border:

```
a { border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

This will keep the box at the correct size until it is hovered.

Comment: With the first one it would fix Firefox but break other browsers, for the second it just doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using appearence:button on hover only anyway? It's bad practice. Have you thought about styling it as a button yourself, or better yet, use an actual button? You can make an icon for it by using an adjacent `span` with a background and a `display:inline-block` or an actual image, then shift its position with `position:absolute` and `margin-left`